# Android wear app with Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, wear-os

Currently I'm doing the Facebook Integration for android wear. I followed the all procedures and it's pretty much working good in mobiles. When I'm trying to run same code in android wear, app gets continues crash with below error.

```
04-27 16:47:36.968 2853-2853/com.test.sample E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.test.sample/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.getCookieManager(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:54)
at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.sync(CookieSyncManager.java:107)
at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:544)
at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:569)
at com.facebook.login.WebLoginMethodHandler.getParameters(WebLoginMethodHandler.java:96)
at com.facebook.login.WebViewLoginMethodHandler.tryAuthorize(WebViewLoginMethodHandler.java:69)
at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.tryCurrentHandler(LoginClient.java:254)
at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.tryNextHandler(LoginClient.java:216)
at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.authorize(LoginClient.java:121)
at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.startOrContinueAuth(LoginClient.java:102)
at com.facebook.login.LoginFragment.onResume(LoginFragment.java:153)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2133)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1156)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1277)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2164)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6810)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I've few of questions, will android wear will support the Facebook integration feature? If yes please suggest me the best possible solution's and please revert back for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Som features are disabled in Android Wear API/SDK.
WebView doesn't work on wear devices properly.

You can try to use new Android Wear 2.0. But I can'y guarantee that this code will work.

I would suggest to use handheld device connection instead of wear.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @PrasannaKumarPeddinti , approve the answer if it was helpful